# Select and highlight element by using arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of inline-block boxes. The first box is set active and highlighted. By using the arrow key I want set the boxes next to it as active. Which JS event is best here?

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mg3krnwz/1/)

HTML

```
<ol>
<li class="active"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ol>
```

JS

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
switch(e.which) {
    case 37: // left
     $('li').addClass('active');
    break;

    case 38: // up
     $('li').addClass('active');
    break;

    case 39: // right
     $('li').addClass('active');
    break;

    case 40: // down
     $('li').addClass('active');
    break;

    default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
}
e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

css

```
li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 50px;
border: solid;
counter-increment: step-counter;
margin: 20px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mg3krnwz/2/)

> The up and down can't be accurate because this depends on the style of the sheet

You can use index to specify the index of the element

```
        index--;
    if (index==-1){index=$("#orderedList li").length-1;}
    $('li').removeClass('active');
     $($('li')[index]).addClass('active');
```

Comment: thx, I added the css to the question, that includes the width of the boxes

Comment: @user1477955 it still depends on the width of the page and how many boxes per line

Comment: u need to check exactly how many boxes per line and increment the index by the number of boxes per line